# Speeding-up PowerShell's Test-Connection

Tags: powershell

This is a very simple average ping calculator. It takes ip-addresses from for cycle and then puts result in multidimensional array to sort it. I need to speed-up this script somehow because it takes more then 5 minutes to calculate it all.  I read about **-asjob** but I don't understand how to imply this on my script. Thanks in advance.

```
$hostslist = @() 
$host_counter ++
for ($i = 100; $i -le 254; $i++){
    $a = 192
    $b = 168
    $c = 99
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName "$a.$b.$c.$i" -Count 1 -Quiet){
        $hostslist += ,@($host_counter, "$a.$b.$c.$i" ,(Test-Connection -ComputerName "$a.$b.$c.$i" -Count 10  | measure-Object -Property ResponseTime -Average).average)
    }
}
$hosts_by_ping = $hostslist | sort-object @{Expression={$_[2]}; Ascending=$true}  
echo $hosts_by_ping
```

Comment: **_[1]_** do NOT test the connection twice. [*grin*] **_[2]_** stop using `-Count 10` since that adds one second per count. **_[3]_** try the `-AsJob` parameter. **_[4]_** stop using that inherently slow cmdlet & use the `[System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping]::New().SendPingAsync()` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

`test-connection -count 10` is always going to have 9 seconds of delay in between the attempts.  You can do it in a loop instead.